# ?android:attr/colorPrimary vs ?attr/colorPrimary

Tags: android, android-resources

Could somebody please tell me what the difference is between

```
?android:attr/colorPrimary
```

and

```
?attr/colorPrimary
```

*Whichever i use, result is the same. Altough first option causes `android.view.InflateException` on some devices.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both almost works the same often. when you use `?attr/colorPrimary`, its works totally fine as compiler already knows that 'android' has to be appended.

And regarding you saying that `?android:attr/colorPrimary` gives you exception then in that case, try using the second option only ..

For Example in your styles.xml : The following may/may not work everytime

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary_material_dark</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark_material_dark</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

But this majorly works :

```
<style name="AppTheme"  parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_material_dark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark_material_dark</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

The builder knows that the color comes from `attr` so it's redundant. The documentation states:

> ... you do not need to explicitly state the type ... you can exclude the attr type.

See: [App resources overview: Referencing style attributes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#ReferencesToThemeAttributes)

As for `android:` - the prefix in `android:colorPrimary` refers to an attribute of the material theme (API 21 and later). Without the prefix, `?colorPrimary` will be taken from the support library.